# How can I get the value from TextView with OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have this code to create a dynamic table.
Now I want to attach to every TextView an event at onClick. When I tap on a TextView, I want to get the value and execute a method.
So this is my code:

```
                TableLayout ll=(TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);  

                TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = 
                        new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f);

                TableRow.LayoutParams itemParams = 
                        new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

                int i = 1;
                for (Iterator<OperazioniClienti> it = listaOperazioni.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    OperazioniClienti op = it.next();

                    TableRow row= new TableRow(getActivity());
                    //TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    //row.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

                    data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_edittext_row);
                    data.setLayoutParams(itemParams);

                    TextView codFattura = new TextView(getActivity());
                    codFattura.setText(op.getCodiceFattura().toString());
                    codFattura.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_edittext_row);
                    codFattura.setLayoutParams(itemParams);


                    Double saldo = op.getSaldo();
                    TextView importo = new TextView(getActivity());
                    importo.setLayoutParams(itemParams);
                    importo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_edittext_row);
                    importo.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    importo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //to do
                        }
                    });

                    importo.setText("SALDATA"); 
                    importo.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                    row.addView(codFattura);
                    row.addView(importo);
                    ll.addView(row,i++);
                }
            }
```

I have use this code to attach the onclick event to all TextView but I don't know how can I get the value:

```
importo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //to do
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caller of the method is sent as a parameter.
You can get the text from it, or use a tag to identify it, etc...

```
importo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     TextView myTextView = (TextView)v;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case the `View v`, parameter of `onClick`, is the same view of `importo`. you just need to cast to specific type to access its member

```
importo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     TextView import = (TextView)v;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea not sure about this:

Initiate a list like this

```
List<TextView> botonN = new ArrayList<TextView>();
```

Add YOur TextView in this List after you create dynamically or from xml.

```
 botonN.add(your_textView);
```

And set Click Action

```
    for (int index = 0; index < botonN.size(); index++) {
                botonN.get(index).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                      Here you can get Text
String value = botonN.get(index).getTex().toString();

                    }
                });
            }
```

Again it's just sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method "getText()":

```
final TextView importo = new TextView(getActivity());
importo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = importo.getText();
    }
});
```

Note, that you need to declare your TextView as "final" in order to access it from the inner class.